# IntelliJ IDEA braces, brackets and quotes customize color highlighting

Tags: intellij-idea, quotes, brackets, jetbrains-ide, braces

How to change color of brackets when they are selected  ?

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Go over to Settings, and then just go to this menu:

[image]

Comment: If you have a categorised list, it's under "Code" > "Matched Brace"

Comment: SO, quickly and time safe

Comment: As of 2020, this is now found under Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Code -> Matched Brace.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe the plugin [HighlightBracketPair](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10465-highlightbracketpair) is suitable for you. The plugin will highlight the most left and most right brace pair for you when you move the caret, and you can custom the color the effect.

Java Highlight
[image: java]

Go Highlight
[image: go]

Config Page
[image: settings]

Answer (score 4):

**File => Settings => Editor => Color Scheme => General => Code => Matched brace**